# how to display a html page inside dynamically created silverlight child window

Tags: windows, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to a html page inside a dynamically created silverlight child window without telerik control.

Comment: In-browser or out-of-browser?  I assume Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 2):

The telerik control isn't doing anything you can't do yourself with enough effort - it's all just transparent user code.

So, you could create  `<div>` and position it carefully just like the telerik control does - but of course this can be a lot of work (that's why folks would want to pay for their control).

This also only works when the plugin is windowless, which has lots of trade-offs (see MSDN - for example, accessibility support is greatly reduced or gone entirely, I can't recall which).

In out-of-browser mode, you can use the `WebBrowser` control, in case that helps should you wish to make your app available OOB later.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these links:
1. http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/51784.aspx or
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/05/10/integrating-html-into-silverlight-applications.aspx

It can help

Comment: or this one 3. http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/09/15/Displaying-HTML-in-Silverlight.aspx